# Is it two or three ellipsis when using it with a question mark?

Tags: ellipses

When using ellipsis with a question mark, how would it be written?

Would it be written as this:

> "*So are you going to close the door..?*"

Or would it by written as this:

> "*So are you going to close the door...?*"

My first example shows two of the ellipsis, while my other examples shows three. Which is correct?

Comment: The ellipsis is a symbol for words unwritten.  The question is additional.  "*So, are you going to close the door... ?*" (I like more space).

Comment: The dots are not single ellipses. The dots are dots. Three dots are a common way to indicate an ellipsis. Two dots are not generally considered as such an indication.

Comment: An ellipsis is written as three dots. An ellipsis followed by a question mark is written as three dots followed by a question mark.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis):

> The most common form of an ellipsis is a row of three periods or full
>   stops (. . .) or a precomposed triple-dot glyph (…). The usage of the
>   em dash (—) can overlap the usage of the ellipsis, especially in
>   dialogue. **Style guides often have their own rules governing the use of
>   ellipses.** For example, The Chicago Manual of Style recommends that an
>   ellipsis be formed by typing three periods, each with a space on both
>   sides. [emphasis added]

There is no universally accepted standard for the form or use of the ellipsis.
See Wikipedia, a more authoritative source, or any of a number of style manuals for additional information on the use of spaces, the role of periods, etc.

I agree with @Dan that the question mark is in addition to the ellipsis, which is its own mark of punctuation. Your second example with three dots represents common usage.

Comment: Wikipedia is not an authoritative site.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I don't disagree, but it's good enough in this case to get the point across that form and use of the ellipsis is a matter of style.

Comment: What I think you are saying, and I agree with you, is that the three-dot ellipsis, when it is accepted as valid, is a piece of punctuation in its own right and not a row of three dots. As such the dot at the base of a question mark or exclamation mark cannot replace the third dot of the ellipsis as an ellipsis, a question mark, an exclamation mark and a full stop (sorry, I'm British, a period is a length of time to me) are four separate pieces of  punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

The Chicago Manual of Style now (2018) accepts the use of the precomposed triple-dot glyph (…) **ctl+alt+period** (in MS Word).

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't really cover which, if any, other forms might be acceptable, or what to do when the triple-dot character isn't available. Or, more to the point, whether the use of a question mark makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

According to the rule that defines the ellipsis it is always represented by a sequence of three dots, or in modern fonts, by the ellipsis character, that is made of a character with the three dots in it.

Examples of the three dots sequence: ...
And the three dots character: …
(You can copy and paste the one and the other in a text editor program and change the font to a monospace font like Courier to appreciate the differences)

So by definition, and replying to the question “Is it two or three ellipsis when using it with a question mark?”:
**It is one ellipsis** (which is always made up of three dots).

You can find the definition in any english dictionary, for instance:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ellipsis
Check the section “ellipsis noun (PRINTED MARK)”.

Using your example, the correct one would be:

> "So are you going to close the door...?"

Also according to [The Chicago manual of Style Online](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/search.epl?q=ellipsis%20question%20mark&site=cms16live&search_edition=16); [16th ed.] 13.52 Ellipses with other punctuation
“(…), a colon, a semicolon, a question mark, or an exclamation point — may precede or follow three (but...never four) ellipsis points.(…)”

So, your eample can also be:

> "So are you going to close the door? ..."

Comment: Is the space (? ...) in the second case only intentional?

Comment: As a styling option, it’s preferable to put the ellipsis after the question mark because the sentence is complete:
"So are you going to close the door?..."
And to put it before the question mark if the sentence is incomplete:
"So are you going to close the…?"
This rule is recommended in some languages, for instance, the Spanish language.

Comment: The space (?...) in the second case is a matter of style and it’s optional. It can be with or without the space. I find it more readable with the space because the sentence seems to be complete.